# Ember retry transition from a failed promise with new query params

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a route called `estates` where users will see a list of estates they own and from which they can view the details of one estate.

In order to enter the `estate` route, I must pass an `estate_id` and a `mode` parameter. The mode is, by default, set to `open`

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.queryRecord('estate', params);
},
```

In some cases can return an error asking for a different mode. In that situation, the users will be prompted to choose either between "backup" or "saved" via a popup, since it must be a user's made decision.
I tried the following expecting the `queryParamsDidChange` hook to retry the transition but it did not work since Ember has not entered yet the `estate` route.
So how can I could I retry a transition that never resolved with modified query params?

Estate model extract:

```
queryParams: {
  mode: {
    refreshModel: true,
    replace: true
  }
},


actions: {
  error(reason, transition) {
    // 1. Abort the transition so that we don't default to the error page.
    transition.abort();

    // 2. Set controller's previousTransition property so that we can retry it.
    this.controllerFor('estate').set('previousTransiton', transition);

    // 3. Parse the error
    const promiseErrors = reason.errors;

    for (let e=0; e<promiseErrors.length; e++) {
      switch(promiseErrors[e].reason) {
        case 'backupOrSaved':
          this.send('showErrorOnEstateOpen');
          return;
      }
    }
  },
},
```

Estate controller extract:

```
queryParams: ['mode'],
mode: 'open',

eventBusService: Ember.inject.service('event-bus'),

_listen: function() {
  this.get('eventBusService').on('alterEstateOpenMode', this,   '_alterOpenMode');
}.on('init'),

_alterOpenMode(mod) {
  this.set('mode', mod.mode);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the way to do it, but if I were in your situation, I would just go about reconstructing a new transitionTo with different query params from the old transition.

If you have no dynamic segments to your transition, you could simply do

```
//your transition
var transition = someSavedTransition;
var newQueryParams = {foo: "foo"};
this.transitionTo(transition.targetName, newQueryParams);
```

If you have dynamic segments, or you need this to be more generic, you will need to extract the `transition.params` and probably `transitionTo.apply(route, anArrayYouBuilt)` where `arrayYouBuilt` has the transition at index `0`, all the models index `1->(n-1)` and the query params at `n`, where n = number of dynamic segs + 1.

Lastly, the transition has `queryParmas` on its object so if you want to replace only one of the queryParams and keep the rest in your new transitionTo, `$.extend(transition.queryParams, {keyToReplace: valueToReplace});`

hope that helps